# How do I accept a string of text during a go cli function?

Tags: go

I'm trying to work on a PoC with adding exec.Command's to cli plugin, however I'm struggling with how to get it to accept user input with the command.  I admit I am fairly new to Go, coming from PHP and Bash scripting so...I am sure I'm missing something very basic here and it's a little embarrassing.

I've tried setting variables, adding the variables to the output, adding in bufio, and trying to prompt with no luck.

`out, err := exec.Command("mtr", "-c", "10", "-r", destIP).Output()`

was the most recent fail...

```
type Mtr struct{}

func (m *Mtr) Run(command []string, context plugin.PluginContext, ui terminal.UI) {
    // var destIP string - commented out simply so I could rebuild the file and get the plugin working again.

    ui.Say("")
    ui.Say(terminal.AdvisoryColor("Wait while we run a traceroute..."))
    ui.Say("")

    out, err := exec.Command("mtr", "-c", "10", "-r").Output()
    if err != nil {
        ui.Say(fmt.Sprintf("%s", err))
    }
    output := string(out[:])

    table := ui.Table([]string{"", ""})

    table.Add("", output)
    table.Print()
```

I literally just want it to be able to accept something like this

mainprogram plugin mtr 
Currently I have it set to just force Google, but that is not really what I want out of this...

```
out, err := exec.Command("mtr", "-c", "10", "-r", "8.8.8.8").Output()
```

---

Current output with the botched attempts yields -

```
Shawns-MBP-2:directoryhere $ mainprog plugin mtr 4.4.4.4

Wait while we run a traceroute...



Shawns-MBP-2:directoryhere$

With the forced Google DNS, it obviously shows -

Shawns-MBP-2:directoryhere $ mainprog plugin mtr

Wait while we run a traceroute...


   Start: 2019-05-03T15:41:18-0500   
   HOST: stuff   Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev   
     1.|-- stuff   0.0%    10    1.6   1.7   1.2   3.1   0.5   
     2.|-- stuff  0.0%    10    2.6   6.5   2.0  12.4   4.5   
     3.|-- stuff               0.0%    10    3.3   3.3   2.7   4.1   0.4   
     4.|-- stuff       0.0%    10   13.6  12.2   9.1  15.6   2.5   
     5.|-- stuff               0.0%    10    9.2  12.9   9.2  17.7   2.5   
     6.|-- stuff              0.0%    10    8.7   9.1   8.0  10.5   0.6   
     7.|-- stuff               0.0%    10    9.1   9.2   8.2  10.1   0.5   
     8.|-- stuff            0.0%    10   10.3  10.1   9.7  10.4   0.3   
     9.|-- stuff              0.0%    10    8.8   9.2   8.5  10.7   0.6   
    10.|-- google-public-dns-a.googl  0.0%    10    8.7   8.9   8.2  10.0   0.4
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're having trouble with. Are you just looking for [`os.Args`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables)?

Comment: Tried that, but not working either....unless I used it wrong which could totally be the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
func main() {
    out, err := exec.Command("mtr", "-c", "10", "-r", os.Args[1]).Output()
    if err != nil {
        ui.Say(fmt.Sprintf("%s", err))
    }
}
```

?

Build it into a binary and invoke with the IP/domain as an argument.

Read https://gobyexample.com/command-line-arguments for more details

Comment: Tried that but no luck :(

```Shawns-MBP-2:ibmcloud-support-cli shawnandrews$ ibmcloud support mtr google.com

Wait while we run a traceroute...

      
      
Shawns-MBP-2:ibmcloud-support-cli shawnandrews$```

Comment: @ShawnAndrews: did you read the link I posted ? I susped that in your invocation `os.Args[1]` is something else - did you print it out? `os.Args` is *all the command-line arguments* of your program

Comment: Yeah...but, maybe I'm just in over my head at this point and need to spend some more time reading up on Go because it just doesn't make sense to me.  This feels way different than a typical command line examples I was building during the first couple weeks of learning Go because I'm building a plugin for a larger command line instead.

Comment: @ShawnAndrews: nothing here is Go specific. All languages have a similar array of command-line arguments. When your invocation is "./program arg" then arg is os.Args[1], but obviously when your invocation is "./program foo bar arg" then arg is not os.Args[1] but os.Args[3], etc. Plugins usually have ways to pass arguments in a standard way, so you should check the overall style of the application you're hooking into

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that makes a lot of sense now.  I think I'm going to have to get with the team who owns the bigger app and ask them how they make it work because referencing os.Args[3] just pukes an index out of range, or google some more in the meantime to see what I suck at this lol.

Comment: Well thanks to your help, you pointed me in the right direction and I was able to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

After being pointed in the right direction, finally figured it out -

```
dest := os.Args[2]
out, err := exec.Command("mtr", "-c", "10", "-r", dest).Output()
```

That got it working to accept input and verified it's accepting both IPs and domains.  This opens up a whole new world of possibilities now :D